# Adding items to ListView causes first item appear again and again

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, listadapter, dynamically-generated

When the app starts, I load some objects from the Device's SD Card and add them to a ListView.

```
Objects = new ArrayList<DataObject>();
Items = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();
Adapter = new MenuItemAdapter(this, Items);

listView.setAdapter(Adapter);

LoadObjects();
```

When I load objects I deserialize the object, check it's unique ID and if it's already in the list of Objects it should not be added. My method LoadObjects loads tries to load all files in a directory with a given extension. Then if successful, tries to load it into the Items list by using this method:

```
private boolean LoadObject(DataObject obj)
{
     for (DataObject do : Objects)
     {
          if (do.GetID().equals(obj.GetId())
              return false;
     }

     boolean added = Objects.add(do);

     if (added)
     {
          Items.add(new MenuItem(do.GetID(), do.GetName());
          Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }

     return added;
}
```

When this method is run "onCreate" it works fine, it loads in all the objects that can be loaded and is stored on the SD Card. When I try to add one after this method, the first item appears in the list where the new item should be added. I input a new name with a Dialog to create a new DataObject, which will later call LoadObject(new DataObject(name));

I've tried:

1. Resetting the Items adapter
2. Adding a "Add" method on the custom Adapter so that instead of adding to Items, I add through the Adapter by Adapter.Add(new DataObject(name)) which adds to it's own list; I also have a SetList adapter, to recreate the list without success.
3. Skip the notifyDataSetChanged
4. Cleared the Object list, Items list, Create a new Adapter each time - reloading all Objects, all MenuItem's, recreating the adapter and setting a new List - all with the same result.
5. Skip LoadObjects() and just let all newly added items appear, first one is correct - but whatever I add later shows up as the same as #1 from the ListView.

And I have to use FragmentActivity and not ListActivity because I have some Dialogs I need to show.

Simply put, I use the ListView to show specific Files from the SD Card to be able to load them onto another Activity later - but this hinders me from adding any new items without having to restart the Activity just to show new items, which means I need to be able to start out with an empty list and then

Answer (score 0):

Probably becouse you use `Adapter` that have multiple references. Try to rename and don't name variables with uppercase.(see also import list to see what `Adapter` did you have there)

Comment: For your curiosity, I renamed it to "listAdapter" and the same thing occurs. But I've just noticed something else, written in the other answer as a comment... Not sure what causes it. But it starts to repeat itself more and more often.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt #4 has to work. Give next `loadObject()` a shot:

```
private boolean LoadObject(DataObject obj)
{
     for (DataObject do : Objects)
     {
          if (do.GetID().equals(obj.GetID())
              return false;
     }

     Objects.add(obj);
     Items.add(new MenuItem(obj.GetID(), obj.GetName());
     Adapter = new MenuItemAdapter(this, Items);
     listView.setAdapter(Adapter);

     return true;
}
```

Comment: Does not work. But it appears that after adding a few items, the list starts to repeat itself. In my case, if I 6 items in the list "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" and when I try to add "g", "a" appears again. But this has occured again later on. I've just rewritten the whole activity to the bare minimum of loading and adding objects to the list. It's just a RelativeLayout with a ListView in it.

Comment: Possible `equals()` of `DataObject` id has flaw. By the way ArrayList `add()` [always returns true](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)). `added` check is obsolete.

Comment: String.equals(anotherString) is the way to compare two string rather than if (string == anotherString) which almost certainly returns false. I've gotten so many bugs due to this error because I'm normally a C# programmer, which means I've had to change this all around to fix bugs. Whenever this method has applied, it has worked to check two strings against eachother.

Comment: But, still, I load the objects from the SD card only once, then whenever I add a new item, this method is what's called. Which means I don't currently reload all new files from the SD Card, instead after the dialog "Add new" I call this method, so it shouldn't add objects that already is added. Because all objects added are newly added objects.

Comment: @Deukalion you could try updated `loadObject()` edition.

Comment: Why do you use foreach loop instead of `Objects.contains(obj)` within `LoadObject()`?

Comment: Which means I have to add override the equals method and compare my items, when all I need is to compare one "ID" string that I know will be unique upon creation.

Comment: Sorry for off the off topic but for the purpose of maintainability and code clearness `equals()` and `hashCode()` overriding is highly advertisable.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the problem occured due to a ListView being inside a RelativeLayout, altough I can't figure out why.

This is how my Layout was first:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/main_menulist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I instead created a new Layout with a ListView only, the problem no longer occured:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_menulist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView>
```

I've only read about how you should not put a ListView in a ScrollView, but I've used this type of solution (perhaps not by dynamically adding items) before and it's worked.